# Regular expression for checking if hashtags exist in a tweet

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if both `#python` and `#conf` hashtags exist in the following tweets:

```
tweets = ['conferences you would like to attend #python #conf',
          'conferences you would like to attend #conf #python']
```

I've tried the code below but it doesn't match with the tweets.

```
import re
for tweet in tweets:
    if re.search(r'^(?=.*\b#python\b)(?=.*\b#conf\b).*$', tweet):
        print(tweet)
```

If I remove the `#` sign from the regex, both tweets matches but it will also match tweets with non-hashtag `python` and `conf` words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` matches at the beginning or end of a word. `#` is not considered as word according to the [`re` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `\b`
>
> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.
>   **A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore
>   characters**, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a
>   non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. Note that formally, \b is
>   defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice
>   versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string

Try following regular expression (`^`, `.*$` are unnecessary):

```
(?=.*#python\b)(?=.*#conf\b)
```

---

```
>>> tweets = ['conferences you would like to attend #python #conf',
...           'conferences you would like to attend #conf #python',
...           'conferences you would like to attend #conf #snake']
>>>
>>> import re
>>> for tweet in tweets:
...     if re.search(r'(?=.*#python\b)(?=.*#conf\b)', tweet):
...         print(tweet)
...
conferences you would like to attend #python #conf
conferences you would like to attend #conf #python
```